# $.ajax working in browser but phonegap is returning the raw code from the file

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

The code/app/repository is on a Zend Server. I update it then use git to push it to github then use phonegap build to build the app. When I test the code in a browser pointed at the Zend Server it works correctly, I get the result "12345". After I have pushed the new code, build the app, update it on my Nexus 7 and run the app I get a crazy result of:

```
"12345","4746904837" =>"99999","047469048372" =>"88888");foreach ($data as $key => $value){if($key===$qs){$returnData = $value;}}echo $returnData;?>
```

Why is it giving me all of the script after the matched value?

The $.ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "php/test.php",
            data: "qs=9114901075742714812669",
            datatype: "text"
            })
            .done(function( returnData ) {
                console.log(returnData);
                $( "#info" ).append( returnData );
       });
```

The php

```
<?php
$qs = $_GET['qs']; 
$data = array(
    "9114901075742714812669" =>"12345",                             
    "4746904837" =>"99999",
    "047469048372" =>"88888"    
    );
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    if($key===$qs){
        $returnData = $value;
    }
}
echo $returnData;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses. The problem was of the newb persuasion related to trying to learn to many things at the same time. The ajax call was pointing to a php script in my github repository...so that would never have worked. I fixed and it points to the server now.

I did learn 1 very important lesson while fixing it.

When using PhoneGap and doing an ajax request make sure to include http:// in the url or it will try to call file://php/test.php.

Thanks for the responses all.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX calls are HTTP requests like any other. There's no practical different to the webserver if it was some JS issuing the call, or you typing the url into the browser's address bar. If you're getting code back instead of output, then there's something wrong with your server.

Most likely your browser is getting code back as well, but the `<?` is causing it to be interpreted as an unknown HTML tag:

```
<?php
^--- start of "html"
    "9114901075742714812669" =>"12345",                             
                              ^-- end of "html" tag
```

Hit the address in your browser again and do a "view source" - you'll likely see ALL of the php source code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your server isn't executing the php code but returning the text of the php file. If you replace

`$( "#info" ).append( returnData );`

with

`$( "#info" ).text( returnData );`

you'd see that all of the text of your php script is being returned.